# Run a Coded UI test from VS in Vsts

Tags: azure-devops, coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines

I created a new coded UI test on VS2017 and after creating a new agent at the agents pool, I have the following error:

> Error calling Initialization method for test class
>   CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest2:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException:
>   **To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process.**

If you are running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the build agent to run as an interactive process.

It means that the agent couldn't interact with the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

The Hosted agent is running as service, so you can’t do Coded UI test on Hosted agent.

You need to setup a private (self-host) agent with interactive mode)

[image]

More information, you can refer to the document:

[Set up environments to run continuous test tasks with your build tasks FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/set-up-continuous-test-environments-builds?view=vsts#q-what-is-required-to-run-ui-tests)

Comment: So you need to answer YES as a service, then change the service properties, or answer NO for run as a service?

Comment: I found a clarification here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts) but I don't think Microsoft hosted agents support the interactive mode.

For advanced requirements host your own agent

- Self hosting an agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts
- Interactive vs service mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#account